# Atypical use of ~させます

Tags: grammar

I came across the following sentence:

> すぐに なおさせますので もうしわけありませんが,もうしばらくおまちください

Please help understand the `~させます` form here.
What would be the translation of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression like "～させます" or "～させしめる (this expression is a little archaic)" are called "使役表現【しえきひょうげん】" in Japanese.

Usually, "使役表現" is translated into "Subject make/have/get Object Verb~"

For example. Translation "すぐに なおさせますので もうしわけありませんが,もうしばらくおまちください" into Japanese like this.

> I apologize for being late and having you waiting. I'm making the person in charge fixing

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.I mistook it to be some form of けんじょうご that I am not aware of.